# Why the RedirectStandardOutput does not have the necessary ANSI codes?

Tags: redirectstandardoutput, ansi-colors

Ok here's a simple Console Application I made to test the `RedirectStandardOutput` of the `Process.StartInfo`.

```
    foreach (c In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(ConsoleColor))
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = c
        Console.WriteLine("Test")
    }
```

And below is the application result.

[image: Result of the Console Application.]

So as we can see the colors show beautifully on the console.

However, when I read the `StandardOutput.BaseStream` there's no color information, no ANSI codes, no nothing.

How do I capture the color information on the redirected stream?

Comment: I'm leaving this question open until I someone can provide me with a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that the streams as given to you by the .NET `Console` class are purely character-based and return only textual data.

To get the extended color info, it would be necessary to P/Invoke the Win32 API [ReadConsoleOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684965(VS.85).aspx).  This will return, among other things, an array of [COLOR_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682013(VS.85).aspx) structs containing the color attributes for each character.  You might want to look at the [ReadConsoleOutput pinvoke.net page](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/ReadConsoleOutput.html) to get started.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for, because the ReadConsoleOutput reads the console screen as a whole, while what I want is to be able to read the color information as the console process is writing data to the stdout (and obviously stderr).